# OpenCV "Blured Corners" Detector (C++)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, feature-detection

I am using OpenCV 3.1 and Visual Studio C++.

**The goal**

I want to detect corners, not curves, rectangles or circles. This means, I want to find the locations of blurred characters. Here area areas of my interest:

[image: Areas of interest]

The red areas have higher priority because they are more blurred than the orange one which can be detected with the current Shi-Tomasi corner detector .

**What I have tried**

I have tested Shi-Tomasi corner detector - code is placed in this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/good_features_to_track/good_features_to_track.html which is great to locate areas with text when you have sharp images. I would like to find algorithm using OpenCV which has similar (very good) performance and can detect blured text. The areas where the text is blured too much (it is not possible to read it - to detect corners) should be ignored. Also the areas which have good sharpness should be ignored.

Here is example what I tried - this is the result from the Shi-Tomasi tutorial:

This is source image:

[image: Source image]

And this is what I get

[image: Results]

the upper image parameters minDistance=5, qualityLevel=0.01, the lower image minDistance=10, qualityLevel=0.05 the rest of params are same for both images:

```
int blockSize = 3; bool useHarrisDetector = false; double k = 0.04;
```

The wrong result is that it have not found the blured text - the number "195" in upper right area or bottom left, e.g. the "14 ms" and/or "19 ms". 
Rather it have found the best sharp results which is not what I want.

I believe if I could use some kind of kernel which would blur the sharp areas and sharp the blured areas, maybe then the Shi-Tomasi corners detector could find the results.

Any tips how to reach the goal?

Comment: Don't expect much reliability from this case. The garbage in/garbage out principle will apply in full.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of small idea but it may be performance-exhausted.

iterate through your image window by window (3*3 or bigger for better performance) and in each iteration do:

1. Blur this window.
2. Compute the `cv::Norm` between the window before blurring and after blurring. Store this value some where for each window.

These values have properties which are:

1. They are low when the blur is high.
2. They are high when the blur is low

Now go through these values and find values that meet your criteria.